# Display null for column if no row found

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT s.first_name, s.last_name, tgs.group_identifier
FROM staff s
JOIN staff_training st
ON s.staff_id = st.staff_id
JOIN training_group_staff tgs
ON st.staff_training_id = tgs.staff_training_id
WHERE st.staff_course_id = '164'
```

`training_group_staff` only contains the `staff_training_id` and `training_group_id`

This statement works as expected and returns all staff names attending course 164 AND have been placed into a group (identified with the `group_identifier` field).

What I am attempting to do is display all users on training course 164 and if no group selected (there won't be a row for the specific `staff_training_id` in `training_group_staff`) then return null for that column.

**Visual Example**

Current Statement Returns:

```
first_name  |  last_name  |  group_identifier
 Jim        |   Jones     |   3
 Harry      |   Jones     |   6
```

What I am attempting to return is:

```
first_name  |  last_name  |  group_identifier
 Jim        |   Jones     |   3
 Harriet    |   Smith     |   NULL   // No row in training_group_staff
 Harry      |   Jones     |   6
```

I have tried several joins, however seem to return the same results - is the desired output possible in one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `LEFT JOIN`. Should be what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Try using an explicit `LEFT JOIN` when joining the `training_group_staff` table
2. An IF statement checking to see if the value is empty and setting it to `null`

```
SELECT s.first_name    
    , s.last_name    
    , IF(tgs.group_identifier = '', null, group_identifier) AS group_identifier    
FROM staff s    
JOIN staff_training st    
ON s.staff_id = st.staff_id    
LEFT JOIN training_group_staff tgs    
ON st.staff_training_id = tgs.staff_training_id    
WHERE sm.staff_course_id = '164'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [outer joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_joins) when you want to include `NULL`s following `JOIN` operations:

```
SELECT s.first_name, s.last_name, tgs.group_identifier
FROM staff s
JOIN staff_training st
JOIN ON s.staff_id = st.staff_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN training_group_staff tgs
ON st.staff_training_id = tgs.staff_training_id
WHERE st.staff_course_id = '164'
```