# Display rest of row with null or 0 in place for columns not found

Tags: mysql, sql

Question similar to this I think:
[Display null for column if no row found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500890/display-null-for-column-if-no-row-found)

I have tried several joins, but can't get the results I require.

SQL statement:

```
SELECT months.month, SUM(job_details.price_each*job_details.quantity) AS sum_monthly_price, DATE_FORMAT(job.order_date, '%M') AS order_date, customer.company_name 
FROM months 
JOIN job on months.month = month(job.order_date) 
JOIN job_details on job.job_id = job_details.job_id 
JOIN customer on job.company_id = customer.company_id 
WHERE months.month > month(date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 month)) 
AND months.month <= month(NOW()) 
AND customer.company_id = 6 
GROUP BY months.month 
ORDER BY months.month asc
```

Current Statement Returns:

```
month    |  sum_monthly_price  |  order_date  |   company_name
  7      |        100          |     July     |      test
  9      |        300          |  September   |      test
```

What I am attempting to return is:

```
month    |  sum_monthly_price  |  order_date  |   company_name
  7      |        100          |     July     |      test
  8      |         0           |     NULL     |      test
  9      |        300          |  September   |      test
  10     |         0           |     NULL     |      test
```

The months table just has 1 to 12 integers to see if there are any jobs for the previous 4 months. But I require it to display 0 in sum_monthly_price if there were no jobs for a particular month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you need to use an `OUTER JOIN` to get results for the missing months, but you also need a `CROSS JOIN` to get the Company name correctly -- if not, it will show up as `NULL`:

```
SELECT months.month,
     SUM(job_details.price_each*job_details.quantity) AS sum_monthly_price, 
     DATE_FORMAT(job.order_date, '%M') AS order_date, 
     customer.company_name 
FROM months CROSS JOIN customer 
    LEFT JOIN job on job.company_id = customer.company_id 
         AND months.month = month(job.order_date) 
    LEFT job_details on job.job_id = job_details.job_id 
WHERE months.month > month(date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 month)) 
    AND months.month <= month(NOW()) 
    AND customer.company_id = 6 
GROUP BY months.month 
ORDER BY months.month asc
```

Comment: Many thanks, that's almost perfect. One thing I am getting NULL for  'sum_monthly_price' if no record. How can I get that to be 0? I am thinking an ifnull() but not sure how to implement that with sum()

Comment: You can use `COALESCE()` -- `COALESCE( SUM(job_details.price_each*job_details.quantity),0)`

Answer (score 1):

You need `left join`.  You also need to move the condition on the `customer` table to the `on` clause.  I think this might do what you want:

```
SELECT months.month, SUM(job_details.price_each*job_details.quantity) AS sum_monthly_price, 
       DATE_FORMAT(job.order_date, '%M') AS order_date, customer.company_name 
FROM months LEFT JOIN
     job
     on months.month = month(job.order_date) LEFT JOIN
     job_details
     on job.job_id = job_details.job_id LEFT JOIN
     customer
     on job.company_id = customer.company_id AND customer.company_id = 6 
WHERE months.month > month(date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 month)) AND
      months.month <= month(NOW()) 
GROUP BY months.month 
ORDER BY months.month asc;
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this won't return the `company_name` correctly for `null` records.  I also would question the `SUM` logic as this would return the `SUM` for all companies, not just for `id = 6`.