# Between dates query not working, now we're in a new year

Tags: mysql, sql

I created this query last year for selecting the previous 6 months from a database.

```
SELECT months.month_name,
COALESCE(SUM(job_details.price_each*job_details.quantity),0) AS sum_monthly_price, customer.company_name
FROM months 
CROSS JOIN customer 
LEFT JOIN job on job.company_id = customer.company_id 
AND months.month = month(job.order_date)
AND job.order_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
LEFT JOIN job_details on job.job_id = job_details.job_id
WHERE months.month > month(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH))
AND months.month <= month(NOW())
AND customer.company_id = 2
GROUP BY months.month 
ORDER BY months.month asc
```

Issue seem to be with the where clause `WHERE months.month > month(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)) AND months.month <= month(NOW())`

It seems before the new year it was working as it was looking between month 06 to 12. However now I'm trying to look between months 07 to 01.

When my query runs, now that we are in a new year, it doesn't return any results. If I change my where to just `WHERE months.month > month(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH))`, as in just from a date, it will return everything to month 12, because obviously I'm doing greater than and it will ignore month 01.

I don't see why my original query is not working, as it should still be doing greater than one date and less than the other.

Can anyone work out what I've done wrong.

Comment: What you seem to have done wrong is store the month without the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your original query does not work, because it does "greater than july **and** less than january", which obviously returns no results.
If you just want to get results for the last six months (as in, from July 18th till Jan 18th), you can just replace

```sql
WHERE months.month > month(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH))
AND months.month <= month(NOW())
```

with

```sql
WHERE job.order_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND NOW()
```

If you actually want to get data for the last six full months (as in, from July 1st till Jan 18th), then you can do something like:

```
WHERE job.order_date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH), "%Y-%m-01 00:00:00") AND NOW()
```

UPDATE: per the discussion in the comments, the requirement is to select empty months too. This is how such a query can be written:

```sql
SELECT months.month_name,
COALESCE(SUM(job_details.price_each*job_details.quantity),0) AS sum_monthly_price, customer.company_name
FROM months 
CROSS JOIN customer 
LEFT JOIN job on job.company_id = customer.company_id 
AND months.month = month(job.order_date)
AND job.order_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
LEFT JOIN job_details on job.job_id = job_details.job_id
WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), CONCAT("%Y-", month, "-%d")) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND NOW() OR DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR), CONCAT("%Y-", month, "-%d")) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND NOW())
AND customer.company_id = 2
GROUP BY months.month 
ORDER BY months.month asc
```

Comment: Ok, `WHERE job.order_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND NOW()` this does work and gets all data for between the dates. But I created a months table as I required that if there was no data for a particular month I still got the month name along with zero as the data. Hopefully that makes sense. Unfortunately your where skips out months that have no data.

Comment: Try to add `OR job.order_date IS NULL`. Also be careful with OR and AND precedence, you might want to add parens, like so: `(WHERE job.order_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND NOW() OR job.order_date IS NULL)`

Comment: no, `job.order_date is null` seems to select all data. It doesn't like the parens and flags up an error.

Comment: Here's the question I posted in regards to the query before, it shows what I was aiming for. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26315186/display-rest-of-row-with-null-or-0-in-place-for-columns-not-found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26315186/display-rest-of-row-with-null-or-0-in-place-for-columns-not-found)

Comment: Ah, yes, it makes sense. Yes, this is tricky then. Try this out: `(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), CONCAT("%Y-", month, "-%d")) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND NOW() OR DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR), CONCAT("%Y-", month, "-%d")) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND NOW())`

Comment: Going to take me a while to work out how that works, but seems to. Thanks a lot.