# Add missing month into query result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very simple query: http://pastebin.com/CGPZM14U

It counts articles per month in a given year. Let's assume that I have nothing written in August 2014. Obviouslty instead of having August = 0 I will have September next after July.

How to add missing months with count equal to 0. I have some working examples but I'm looking for as simple and clean solution as possible.

Comment: It would behoove you to put the query in the question, rather than in an external link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table with all the months, and then left join it with your query. Along the lines of

```sql
select count(1) as count, months.month, year(published_at) as year
from months left join articles on months.month = month(published_at)
where published_at >= (now() - interval 1 year) and published_at <= now()
group by month(published_at)
order by year asc, month asc
```

It will kind of work, but it will return you results from Jan to Dec, and won't give you years. A similar question was asked before, then I came up with a very complex query, so if you don't find anything simpler, consider taking a look:

[Between dates query not working, now we're in a new year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28014862/between-dates-query-not-working-now-were-in-a-new-year/28015033#28015033)

Comment: This is the correct approach, but you need to rather define a dates table and get the `year` from it along with the `month`.  Without, the year from the `published_at` field will be `null`.

Comment: Yes, I pointed out the problem in the answer :) But your solution to that problem is actually good.

Answer (score -1):

Replace `Count` with `ISNULL(Count, 0)`