# How to find the number of months missing from January to July of a Year in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, count

i have a View named view_uncollected.

```
|RemitNo|ID|Employer|  AP_From |  AP_To   |Amount|
|   1   |1 |    a   |2016-01-01|2016-01-31|200.00|
|   2   |1 |    a   |2016-02-01|2016-02-29|200.00|
|   3   |1 |    a   |2016-03-01|2016-03-31|200.00|
|   4   |1 |    a   |2016-04-01|2016-05-31|400.00|
|   5   |1 |    a   |2016-06-01|2016-06-30|200.00|
|   6   |2 |    b   |2016-01-01|2016-03-31|600.00|
|   7   |2 |    b   |2016-04-01|2016-04-30|200.00|
|   8   |2 |    b   |2016-05-01|2016-05-31|200.00|
|   9   |3 |    c   |2016-01-01|2016-01-31|200.00|
|  10   |3 |    c   |2016-01-01|2016-01-31|200.00|
|  11   |3 |    c   |2016-03-01|2016-03-31|200.00|
```

I need to find how many MONTHS is missing from January - July of 2016.

Based on the table above there are some complex cases:

- Employer(a) paid from January - June 2016 ONLY. One month is missing from it.
- Employer(b) paid from January - May 2016 ONLY. 2 months is missing from it.
- Employer(c) paid January (2x) and March. 5 months is missing from it. *We will not consider the other Payment of January as February.*

How can i count the months missing from each employer?

What I did is use this `7 - COUNT(RemitNo) GROUP BY ID` because i thought that each `ONE ROW = ONE MONTH` . but after reviewing my results, some employers have `ONE ROW = 2 MONTHS`, like `RemitNo = 4`. I knew then that is was wrong because it only counts the number of rows not the number of months.

The reason behind this is that we need to know how much remittance is uncollected from January to July of 2016.

Thank you for the suggestions and comments. Sorry for this novice question

Comment: You'll need a calendar table, google for it, plenty of tutorials online

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090379/add-missing-month-into-query-result

Comment: Just wondering if pay several month on the same payment shouldnt the amount be bigger than a single month?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes sir, i'll edit my example now.

Comment: You should also check the description, because data show `a` pay all 6 months in five payments and `b` only miss one with three payments

Comment: Sir, I need to check how many months did the employer missed from January - July 2016. not January to June 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the base query allow you to get the months already paid.

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/BDALSU51372)**

```
SELECT ID, month
FROM YourTable T
JOIN (    
        SELECT 'JAN' as month,'2016-01-01' as start,'2016-01-31' as end UNION ALL
        SELECT 'FEB' as month,'2016-02-01' as start,'2016-02-29' as end UNION ALL
        SELECT 'MAR' as month,'2016-03-01' as start,'2016-03-31' as end UNION ALL
        SELECT 'APR' as month,'2016-04-01' as start,'2016-04-30' as end UNION ALL
        SELECT 'MAY' as month,'2016-05-01' as start,'2016-05-31' as end UNION ALL
        SELECT 'JUN' as month,'2016-06-01' as start,'2016-06-30' as end UNION ALL
        SELECT 'JUL' as month,'2016-07-01' as start,'2016-07-31' as end 
    ) M
    ON T.AP_From <= M.end 
   AND T.AP_To >= M.start;
```

**Partial Result:**

[image]

**Final query:**

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(month) as payed
FROM 
    (
      <First Query>
     ) F
GROUP BY ID;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Sir, is  `SELECT 'MAY' as month,'2016-05-01' as start,'2016-05-31' as end UNION ALL` missing?

Comment: Sir, how about my example in `RemitNo 4` it's from `2016-04-01 - 2016-05-31` it's from April to May

Comment: how about? what is wrong? If you partial result you will see both months there

Answer (score 0):

How about calculate the differnce between the two dates and SUM all the rows.

```
SELECT Employer, 7-SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, AP_from, DATE_ADD(AP_to,INTERVAL 1 DAY))) as missingmonth 
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Employer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following...

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 5 |
| 8 |
+---+

SELECT 7 - COUNT(DISTINCT i) x FROM my_table WHERE i BETWEEN 1 AND 7;
+---+
| x |
+---+
| 4 |
+---+
```

For the purposes of this example, I'm using a simple integer column, which I've called i, but it could just as easily be a date. Others have suggested that you need some kind of calendar, or utility table. I'm demonstrating that you don't. I'm simply deducting the number of (distinct) months/integers found from the number that should exist.

Comment: what does the `i` stand for?

Comment: For the purposes of this example, I'm using a simple integer column, which I've called i, but it could just as easily be a date. Others have suggested that you need some kind of calendar, or utility table. I'm demonstrating that you don't. I'm simply deducting the number of (distinct) months/integers found from the number that should exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
|RemitNo|ID|Employer|  AP_From |  AP_To   |Amount|
|   1   |1 |    a   |2016-01-01|2016-01-31|200.00|
|   2   |1 |    a   |2016-02-01|2016-02-29|200.00|
|   3   |1 |    a   |2016-03-01|2016-03-31|200.00|
|   4   |1 |    a   |2016-04-01|2016-05-31|400.00|
|   5   |1 |    a   |2016-06-01|2016-06-30|200.00|
|   6   |2 |    b   |2016-01-01|2016-03-31|600.00|
|   7   |2 |    b   |2016-04-01|2016-04-30|200.00|
|   8   |2 |    b   |2016-05-01|2016-05-31|200.00|
|   9   |3 |    c   |2016-01-01|2016-01-31|200.00|
|  10   |3 |    c   |2016-01-01|2016-01-31|200.00|
|  11   |3 |    c   |2016-03-01|2016-03-31|200.00|
```

Based on the table above there are some complex cases:

- Employer(a) paid from January - June 2016 ONLY. One month is missing
  from it.
- Employer(b) paid from January - May 2016 ONLY. 2 months is
  missing from it.
- Employer(c) paid January (2x) and March. 5 months is
  missing from it. We will not consider the other Payment of January as
  February.

Now, the way I see it, **employer a** paid the amount due in full from `2016-01-01` to `2016-06-30` and that his payment for the month of `June` was made on `RemitNo 4`. If we were to select the total sum grouped by employer, we would get

```
|Employer|Sum    |
|   a    |1200.00|
|   b    |1000.00|
|   c    | 600.00|
```

Now if we were to assume that each employer needs to pay 200 per month and the number of months to be accumulated is 6 month from `2016-01-01` to `2016-06-30` then the most logical query would be.

`SELECT employer, (200 * 6) - sum(amount) as balance, sum(amount) / 200 as months_due FROM table WHERE AP_FROM => '2016-01-01' AND AP_To <= '2016-06-30' HAVING (200 * 6) - sum(amount) > 0;`

I haven't tested the script, but I believe this is pretty much what you need.

Edit:
I believe this has already been resolved, though no answers were tagged as correct. :]